# How to strip local symbols with a version script

Tags: linker, symbols, visibility, ld, elf

I am compiling a shared ELF library with GCC using `-Wl,--version-script=version.script`

```
MYLIB_1.0 {
    global:
        the_only_symbol_i_want;
    local:
        *;
};
```

This does as advertised; `the_only_symbol_i_want` is exported as a global symbol, but all the other symbols are local.

However I would also like to strip the local symbols. The man page for `ld` says you should use `-Wl,--discard-all` to do this. It's badly named - the docs say it actually discards all local symbols, not all symbols.

However this doesn't seem to actually do anything when combined with `--version-script`.

If I do `strip --discard-all mylib.so` then it *does* work, but I'd like to avoid having to run `strip`.

Is there any way to make `ld` do what I want? Does the version script not have a `discard:` option?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to make ld do what I want?

Depends on which `ld` you use.

If this is GNU `ld`, then adding `-Wl,--strip-all` will result in complete removal of the symbol table (where all the local symbols appear), leaving only the dynamic symbol table (in which local symbols do *not* appear).

Comment: When I wrote the question I didn't actually realise there were two symbols tables! So yeah the best option seems to be `-Wl,--version-script` and `-Wl,--strip-all` (though that's only for neatness really).